# alternative to stream_get_contents in displaying $zip->getStream

Tags: php

Good Day,

is there an alternative way of displaying the output of $zip->getStream instead of stream_get_contents, since str_replace wont work on stream_get_contents and I want to replace some strings in the file before displaying them. I'm currently using

```
$fp = $zip->getStream($path);
$data = file_get_contents($fp);
if ( $data !== false ) {
 echo str_replace("[path]","../mailtemplates/$sql_temp/",$data);
}
```

but it's still not working.

any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `fread` and replace as you go? Why are you using streams, but then not a stream-able code?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen im extracting from a zip file